# Deleting Row From Button Column Within a TableView [Java]

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, javafx-8, action

I have a TableView which generates buttons all along a column:

[image: My program]

Building a task-managing application. I want to be able to delete the row on which the button is located, **not the row which is selected** as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34857007/how-to-delete-row-from-table-column-javafx), when the corresponding button is pressed.

My table class implements EventHandler so the buttons in my TableView run the handle() method when pressed:

```
public TableList(String task, String subject, LocalDate dueDate) {
    this.task = new SimpleStringProperty(task);
    this.subject = new SimpleStringProperty(subject);
    this.dueDate = dueDate;
    this.completed = new JFXButton("Finished");
    completed.setOnAction(this);
}


@Override
public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
    // DELETE ROW HERE
}
```

The only thing missing is how to detect the row on which the buttons are pressed and then delete it (since all the buttons run the same handle method). Help much appreciated.

Code dump here for clarity: https://pastebin.com/TGk4CUWh

Comment: ok, there is some source code. But where is the attempt to solve the problem? Did you read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30191264/javafx-tableview-how-to-get-the-row-i-clicked ?

Comment: What does the `DELETE ROW HERE` mean? Solution would be only accepted if the deletion takes place at exactly this designated place? There should be something like a model in place from which the element should be removed resulting in the table having one row less. KeyWord `MVC` or `MVP`

Comment: @michaeak Yes, I did read that thread, and I recall writing in **bold** that I need a solution for deleting the row on which the *button* is clicked, NOT the row that is selected. You're right though, I should have included the attempts to solve the problem, even if it was just 8 hours of digging through SO and youtube as well as trial and error.

Comment: Why I wrote the comment is first because you did not include your own efforts, just something like "insert code here". I could not even see code creating the button. Maybe I oversaw it, but at least it is not provided in the question. Secondly knowing the row at creation time allows you to create a listener during creation time which simply knows the row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a demo. Altered code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29489366/how-to-add-button-in-javafx-table-view). The key is to use `updateItem` in `TableCell`. In the `Button's` `onAction`, remove from the `TableView` at the current index of the `Button`. `getIndex()` gets the buttons current index.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class JustDoIt extends Application
{

    private final TableView<Person> table = new TableView<>();
    private final ObservableList<Person> data
            = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                    new Person("Jacob", "Smith"),
                    new Person("Isabella", "Johnson"),
                    new Person("Ethan", "Williams"),
                    new Person("Emma", "Jones"),
                    new Person("Michael", "Brown")
            );

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage)
    {
        stage.setWidth(450);
        stage.setHeight(500);

        TableColumn firstNameCol = new TableColumn("First Name");
        firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("firstName"));

        TableColumn lastNameCol = new TableColumn("Last Name");
        lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("lastName"));

        TableColumn actionCol = new TableColumn("Action");
        actionCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("DUMMY"));

        Callback<TableColumn<Person, String>, TableCell<Person, String>> cellFactory
                = //
                new Callback<TableColumn<Person, String>, TableCell<Person, String>>()
        {
            @Override
            public TableCell call(final TableColumn<Person, String> param)
            {
                final TableCell<Person, String> cell = new TableCell<Person, String>()
                {

                    final Button btn = new Button("Just Do It");

                    {
                        btn.setOnAction(event -> {
                            table.getItems().remove(getIndex());
                        });
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty)
                    {
                        super.updateItem(item, empty);
                        if (empty) {
                            setGraphic(null);
                            setText(null);
                        }
                        else {
                            setGraphic(btn);
                            setText(null);
                        }
                    }
                };
                return cell;
            }
        };

        actionCol.setCellFactory(cellFactory);

        table.setItems(data);
        table.getColumns().addAll(firstNameCol, lastNameCol, actionCol);

        Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());

        ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().addAll(table);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static class Person
    {

        private final SimpleStringProperty firstName;
        private final SimpleStringProperty lastName;

        private Person(String fName, String lName)
        {
            this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(fName);
            this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lName);
        }

        public String getFirstName()
        {
            return firstName.get();
        }

        public void setFirstName(String fName)
        {
            firstName.set(fName);
        }

        public String getLastName()
        {
            return lastName.get();
        }

        public void setLastName(String fName)
        {
            lastName.set(fName);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @fabian. Code updated. I think I covered all your improvements.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm not really sure how to adapt this to the context of my application though, I've tried breaking my head against this simple thing for days. My tableview and button are in completely different classes && the code above is placed in the main class while I have two seperate classes which I use to create and control my tableview.

Comment: The table cell that contains your button. Use it to set the cell factory.